# Scipy with numerical integration on multiple lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, numerical-integration

I have a graph with steps of span and corresponding values of rotation. I need to perform a numerical integration on each steps to get slope value. I wonder since there is already build-in function in scipy integration like trapezodal rule or simpson rule. How could that be implemented on two array or list of data without any additional function?

[image]

```
import scipy
fraction_of_span = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1]
rotation = [0.33, 1.34, 2.62, 3.41, 3.87, 4.02, 3.87, 3.41, 2.62, 1.34, 0] 
result = scipy.trapz(fraction_of_span, rotation, 10)
```

**expected result:**

```
result = [x0, x1, .........xn]
```

Comment: In the above test you want the area because you are talking about integration, however the word slope is included which may people think about derivations. There are good materials in line what you are asking, perhaps you would like to have a look here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html

Comment: Thanks for reply, in term of beam theory, integration of rotation leads to slope of beam, dubble integration leads to deflection of beam. That should not be combined with derivations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the above proposal

```
import scipy
fraction_of_span = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1]
rotation = [0.33, 1.34, 2.62, 3.41, 3.87, 4.02, 3.87, 3.41, 2.62, 1.34, 0]
result = scipy.trapz(fraction_of_span, rotation, 10)
print(result)
-2.6665
```

Example of already build solution of the above, with simp

```
from scipy.integrate import simps
y = rotation
x = fraction_of_span


result_simps = simps(y, x)
print(result_simps)
2.6790000000000003
```

Note that the results are very similar, slightly different because of the method. Note the sign should be positive since the integration is between only positive values (rotations elements are all positive)

There are good materials in line what you are asking, perhaps you would like to have a look here: docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html

Let try to get a similar vectorial results.

To do that you could go to the functions above mentioned and modify those to get the results. So I go https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L4081-L4169 and modify/create a new one the function as below:

```
def trapz_modified(y, x=None, dx=1.0, axis=-1):
    """
    Integrate along the given axis using the composite trapezoidal rule.
    Integrate `y` (`x`) along given axis.
    Parameters
    ----------
    y : array_like
        Input array to integrate.
    x : array_like, optional
        The sample points corresponding to the `y` values. If `x` is None,
        the sample points are assumed to be evenly spaced `dx` apart. The
        default is None.
    dx : scalar, optional
        The spacing between sample points when `x` is None. The default is 1.
    axis : int, optional
        The axis along which to integrate.
    Returns
    -------
    trapz : float
        Definite integral as approximated by trapezoidal rule.
    See Also
    --------
    sum, cumsum
    Notes
    -----
    Image [2]_ illustrates trapezoidal rule -- y-axis locations of points
    will be taken from `y` array, by default x-axis distances between
    points will be 1.0, alternatively they can be provided with `x` array
    or with `dx` scalar.  Return value will be equal to combined area under
    the red lines.
    References
    ----------
    .. [1] Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule
    .. [2] Illustration image:
           https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Composite_trapezoidal_rule_illustration.png
    Examples
    --------
    >>> np.trapz([1,2,3])
    4.0
    >>> np.trapz([1,2,3], x=[4,6,8])
    8.0
    >>> np.trapz([1,2,3], dx=2)
    8.0
    >>> a = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3)
    >>> a
    array([[0, 1, 2],
           [3, 4, 5]])
    >>> np.trapz(a, axis=0)
    array([1.5, 2.5, 3.5])
    >>> np.trapz(a, axis=1)
    array([2.,  8.])
    """
    y = asanyarray(y)
    if x is None:
        d = dx
    else:
        x = asanyarray(x)
        if x.ndim == 1:
            d = diff(x)
            # reshape to correct shape
            shape = [1]*y.ndim
            shape[axis] = d.shape[0]
            d = d.reshape(shape)
        else:
            d = diff(x, axis=axis)
    nd = y.ndim
    slice1 = [slice(None)]*nd
    slice2 = [slice(None)]*nd
    slice1[axis] = slice(1, None)
    slice2[axis] = slice(None, -1)
    try:
        # MODIFIED HERE
        #ret = (d * (y[tuple(slice1)] + y[tuple(slice2)]) / 2.0).sum(axis)
        ret = d * (y[tuple(slice1)] + y[tuple(slice2)]) / 2.0
    except ValueError:
        # Operations didn't work, cast to ndarray
        d = np.asarray(d)
        y = np.asarray(y)
        # MODIFIED HERE
        #ret = add.reduce(d * (y[tuple(slice1)]+y[tuple(slice2)])/2.0, axis)
        ret = d * (y[tuple(slice1)]+y[tuple(slice2)])/2.0

    return ret
```

We need the following libraries too, at the top of the file/script:

```
from numpy import diff
from numpy import asanyarray
```

Let see the output:

```
>>>trapz_modified(y, x=x)
array([0.0835, 0.198 , 0.3015, 0.364 , 0.3945, 0.3945, 0.364 , 0.3015,
       0.198 , 0.067 ])
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want rather take each steps and integrate over and display result with a list

Comment: Thanks for your solution, exactly that is it, what I seek for!.